# Velocity of a moving object at time t, find the function r(t)

Tags: calculus, vectors

"If the velocity of a moving object at time t is given by v(t) = < -4cost, 2sint, 1> and the object's position at t=0 is <0,4,-2>, then find the function r(t) which gives the position of the object at time t"

I am wondering how can I apply the velocity vector along with the point p=(0,4,-2) in a way that I can derive the original function r(t)?

Comment: The position at t=0 is <0, 4, -2> :) so would the first point be 4-4cost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x(t)-x(0)=\int_0^t v_x(t)dt$$
$$y(t)-y(0)=\int_0^t v_y(t)dt$$
$$z(t)-z(0)=\int_0^t v_z(t)dt$$